# SQL Query , Clients with No Client Contact and No Active Client Contact

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query to get the Name of the Clients where there is no Client Contact record and if there is any Client Contact then they are ended. Please see below table structure.

Table : **Client**

```
Client ID   Client Name
-------------------------
  1            John     
  2            Sean     
  3          Johnson
```

Table : **Client_Contact**

```
Client Contact ID   Client ID   Start Date      End Date
---------------------------------------------------------
        1               1        1/1/1999       2/2/1999
        2               1        1/2/1999       2/3/1999
        3               1        1/3/1999       2/4/1999
        4               2        1/2/2005       1/2/2007
        5               2        1/3/2005         NULL
```

The query will return **Johnson and Sean**.

1. Johnson has no Client Contact , so it is coming up in the Query
2. John has Client Contact but all the Client Contact are ended , so it is coming up in the query
3. Sean has Client Contact but one of the record is not ended , so it is not coming up in the query.

Thanks in advance for the query.

Comment: Suppose you have a row in Client_Contact with StartDate somewhere in future and EndDate is NULL. Should it be considered a valid contact?

Comment: no if End_Date for all records are populated then the client should show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query pattern that I use for queries like this that can give substantial performance gains compared to "left join" patterns, when the tables involved get really large:

```
select c.[Client Name]
from Client c
where not exists
(
select *
from Client_Contact cc
where c.[Client ID] = cc.[Client ID]
    and cc.[End Date] is null
)
```

Comment: Cool. Please mark my response as the best answer if it's working well for you =D

Answer (score 1):

Try ..

```
select distinct cl.*
from Client cl
left outer join Client_Contact clcnt
on cl.[Client ID] = clcnt.[Client ID]
where (clcnt.[Client ID] IS NULL OR clcnt.[End Date] IS NULL)
```

Comment: Checked the answer [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f461b/1). It looks correct

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query might work for you

```
select c.* from client c
    left join (select max([Client Contact ID]) ClientContactID,[Client ID] from client_contact
    group by [client id]) ce on c.[Client ID]=ce.[Client ID]
    left join client_contact ce1 on ce.[Client Contact ID]=ce1.[Client Contact ID]
    where ce.[Client ID] is null
     or ce1.[End Date] is not null
```